# Which part of the page load is running slowly after button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net page written in c# which lists details of a job (date, time and location) and the staff assigned to it all loaded from an SQL server backend. When the page first loads, it loads straight away, no issues.

The form is within an update panel and on a web form with a content page attached to a master page.

When clicking on any asp:button to update the page, the page takes a long time (sometimes a couple of seconds, sometimes > 20 seconds) to respond. One asp:button is to the HTML, another is added by code behind during the page_load process. Both cause the slow response.

I added code to show the page load time at various points after the button has been clicked, the page_load method takes less then 0.2s to load. The _click method for the button takes around the same, so what is taking so long to load?

There are obviously a number of possible reasons for the problem, what I'd like to know is where to start looking? If the page_load time is similar, where else could the problem be lurking?

Removing MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" seems to have sped things up, slightly, but it's still a several second load time.

I've also cleared the _click method to test but, again, the response time was several seconds but the page_load method only took a fraction of a second to load.

Finally, on Azure I checked the logs for the SQL server (as the page loads data from that) and the DTU usage was at 4% max, so I don't believe the issue is there.

On my DEV PC, the response is instantaneous, when loading the site to Azure or a test server, the slowdown happens.

Comment: How are we supposed to guess what's causing poor performance in code we can't see, in an environment you only hint at? Nevertheless, the answer is almost always "log the time it takes to do everything" using whatever diagnostic tools you have available to you.

Comment: You can also use Chrome dev tools to inspect the requests and responses. It could be that your page is writing some massive amount of viewstate, and then when you press a button you're posting all of that back.

Comment: Quick follow up. The HTML code produced by the page is 156kb. The viewstate field about 15k. Does that seem excessive?

The c# code itself is 5,000 lines so a little too large to post here. I'll see if I can cut it down to the relevant bits.

I know people won't be able to give me a specific answer as to what the issue is, I wanted guidance as to why the c# code-behind seems to load in a fraction of a second but the page itself can take several seconds to load on a production server but not a dev box.